# SQL group by query to find only enabled records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like the following, and I'd like to find the name of the persons which are completely disabled.

This is my table:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | name     | enabled |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | person 1 |       1 |
|  2 | person 1 |       0 |
|  3 | person 2 |       0 |
|  4 | person 2 |       0 |
|  5 | person 3 |       1 |
|  6 | person 3 |       1 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

(the `enabled` column represents a boolean)

In this case, I only want to find person 2, because both records are disabled. I don't want to find person 1, because person 1 is still enabled in row 1, and person 3 is completely enabled, so that on should also be excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having max(enabled) = 0;
```

Comment: Awesome. I just came up with `select * from p group by name having sum(enabled) = 0`. Yours is probably better.

Comment: @Erik I really really like this as a solution. It is *exactly* what you're looking for.

Comment: @Erik . . . The two are pretty much equivalent, for your data.

Comment: @Pachonk In the most of cases, Gordon's answers are exactly what the OP is looking for ..! `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
  FROM table
 GROUP BY name
HAVING MIN(enabled) = 0 AND COUNT(1) = 1;
```